# Getting the text contents from a HTML Table without ID by using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to parse a HTML table (it has no id but class name) from a website. However, since it has no id, I have difficulty in printing the contents from the table. But I couldn't figure it out.

[image]

**Edited**
Here you can see the image of Excel file. GTIP Numbers are located at column A. My aim is when the VBA code runs, these GTIP numbers from column A are forwarded to the Search Field named "GTİP Ara" in the website https://www.isib.gov.tr/urun-arama/. As a result, the companies having the selected GTIP will be returned to the columns next specified row.

For the third row, GTIP number "841013000000" has forwarded to the Search Field named GTIP Ara and as a result; Company 2, ... Company 9 are returned to neighbor columns.

Sometimes GTIP numbers return nothing since none of the companies are holding specified number.

For example: 841410819000 will return the companies but 841112101000 will return an error "Aradığınız Sonuç Bulunamadı!". That's why I am trying to add an if statement but it doesn't work properly.

Now, because of a mistake somewhere in my code block; the returned values are same for each GTIP, here you can see the result on second image.
[image]

Sub GrabLastNames()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object
    Dim y As Integer

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://www.isib.gov.tr/urun-arama"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 2

For i = 2 To 269
    objIE.document.getElementById("gtip-ara").Value = _
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells(i, 1).Value
    objIE.document.getElementById("ara").Click
    'If objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("error").getElementsByTagName("span").Value <> "Aradığınız Sonuç Bulunamadı!" Then
        For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("urun-arama-table table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
        y = y + 1
            Next
            y = 2
            Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Please give more detail about the problems you are having, For example, I can see that you are using methods that return collections e.g. getElementByClassName but are not indexing into those collections before attempting to chain the next method. You may also be limited by which methods you can chain.

Comment: It is also useful to use the snippet tool ([edit] then Ctrl + M] to insert the relevant html.

Comment: You have the method getElementByClassName in your code, but the method is actually called `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Guys, I have edited my question, you can see the details up

Answer (score 0):

I only had one working `GTIP` 841410819000, so cant test this more thoroughly.

You don't really need to know the ID, the page has one table, so getting it using `getElemenetsByClassName` like you did, or just `getElementsByTagName` like in my example should work fine. My code is probably the same as yours, just with a few pauses to a: not spam the website, and b: give IE a chance to get itself together (its IE after all).

If you can provide a few more working GTIP values I can test a bit more.

```
' requires reference 'Microft HTML Object Library'
Sub Main()

Dim Browser As New InternetExplorer

Browser.Visible = True

Browser.navigate "https://www.isib.gov.tr/urun-arama"

Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim TableRows As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TableRow As IHTMLElement

Dim SourceRow As Integer
Dim ResultColumn As Integer

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

SourceRow = 2 ' Skip Header

Do
    Debug.Print "Trying " & Sheet.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Value
    Browser.Document.getElementById("gtip-ara").Value = Sheet.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Value
    Browser.Document.getElementById("ara").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Do While Browser.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If Browser.Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Length > 0 Then

        Debug.Print " > Found Results"

        Set TableRows = Browser.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        ResultColumn = 2 ' dont overwrite search term

        For Each TableRow In TableRows
            Sheet.Cells(SourceRow, ResultColumn).Value = TableRow.innerText
            ResultColumn = ResultColumn + 1
        Next TableRow

    Else

        Debug.Print " - No Results Found"

    End If

    If Sheet.Cells(SourceRow + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        SourceRow = SourceRow + 1
    End If

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Loop

Browser.Quit
Set Browser = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update**
Updated my code again, it doesn't spawn lots of windows anymore and prints only the company name (as your example did).

```
' requires Microsoft HTML Object Library
' requires Microsoft XML, v6.0
Sub Main()
Dim XHR As XMLHTTP60

Dim Document As HTMLDocument
Dim ResultRows As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ResultRow As IHTMLElement

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim SheetRow As Integer
Dim SheetColumn As Integer

Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For SheetRow = 2 To LastRow

    Debug.Print "Trying GTIP:" & Sheet.Cells(SheetRow, 1).Value

    Application.StatusBar = "Status: " & Right(String(Len(CStr(LastRow - 1)), "0") & CStr(SheetRow - 1), Len(CStr(LastRow - 1))) & "/" & CStr(LastRow - 1)

    Set XHR = New XMLHTTP60
    XHR.Open "POST", "https://www.isib.gov.tr/urun-arama", False
    XHR.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XHR.send "gtipkategori=" & Sheet.Cells(SheetRow, 1).Value

    Set Document = New HTMLDocument

    Document.body.innerHTML = XHR.responseText

    If Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Length > 0 Then
        Debug.Print " > Found Results"
        SheetColumn = 2 ' First Column to output data into
        Set ResultRows = Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        For Each ResultRow In ResultRows
            Sheet.Cells(SheetRow, SheetColumn).Value = ResultRow.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText ' 0 - company name
            SheetColumn = SheetColumn + 1
        Next

    Else
        Debug.Print " - No Results"
    End If

    Set XHR = Nothing
    Set Document = Nothing

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' slow down requests

Next

Application.StatusBar = "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: 841610100000
841459259000
732211000011
840310900000
841370309000
841899900000
848180810000
741129000000
741210000000
741220000011
741220000019
842129800019
848190000000
851610800019
851610110000
841490009019
830790000018
842121000000
730799800019
830710000018
902610219000
841620100000
848140900000
841911000000
701939000019
841950800000
@NickSlash The above ones are held by few companies which means they will return the content to the Excel rows.

Comment: 841013000000
841090000000
841111001000
841111009000
841112101000
841112109000
841112301000
841112309000
841112801000
841112809000
841121001000
841121009000
841122201000
841122209000
841122801000
841122809000
841181001000
841181009000
841182201000
841182209000
841182601000
841182609000
841182801000
841182809000
841191001000
841191009000
These ones will return error text: "Aradığınız Sonuç Bulunamadı!"

Comment: @UmutTarhan my code appears to work with the gtip values supplied.